# If for every prime $p$, $a\bmod p\leq b\bmod p$, where nonnegative residues are considered, then show that $a=b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> Source: [here](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ex46wang/Weekly/2019/A6.pdf).

> Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive integers so that for every prime $p$, $a\bmod p\leq b\bmod p$, where nonnegative residues are considered. Show that $a=b$.

Note that the question is trivial if $a\bmod p = b\bmod p$ for all primes $p$.

Clearly $a\leq b$; if not then for any prime $p > a,b$, $a\bmod p > b\bmod p$. It's clear that it suffices to consider primes $p\leq b$, but one can probably strengthen this inequality (e.g. $p\leq a$). As a particular example, consider $a=3, b=5.$ Then $a\bmod 5 > b\bmod 5$ and $5$ is the only prime p where the inequality $a\bmod p\leq b\bmod p$ fails. For $a=4,b=6, a\bmod 3 > b\bmod 3.$ Let $e_p(n)$ denote the highest exponent of $p$ dividing $n$ when $p$ is prime and $n$ is a positive integer. The hint said to show that for every prime $p\leq a$, $e_p({b\choose a}) \leq m(p)-1$, where $$m(p) = e_p(\mathrm{lcm}(b,b-1,\cdots, b-a+1)) = \max\{e_p(b),e_p(b-1),\cdots, e_p(b-a+1)\}.$$ We have by Legendre's formula that $$e_p({b\choose a}) = e_p(b!)-e_p((b-a)!) - e_p(a!) = \sum_{i\ge 1} \left\lfloor \frac{b}{p^i}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{b-a}{p^i} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{a}{p^i}\right\rfloor.$$ But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I know that $e_p(a-b) = \min\{e_p(a),e_p(b)\}$ whenever $e_p(a)\neq e_p(b).$ We then need to show $b\ge 2a$ and that ${b\choose a}$ is too big.